# htaccess don't protect folders, accessed from central index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory, .htpasswd

I have this structure, where 'param' determines which folder must access to:

index.php?param

```
./folder1/ (index.php + .htaccess)
./folder2/ (index.php + .htaccess)        
...
```

Where index.php do: `...require(key($_GET)."/index.php")...`

Every folder have an .htaccess that require authentication by different user names. The problem is, when I authenticate for first time to one of them, then allow me to access to the other folders without their specific authentication. Why?

PD: I have my motivations for do "require(key($_GET)."/index.php")" instead of simply do "/folder1".

Answer (score 0):

If you use `require` then PHP is loading the index.php file and HTTP Auth isn't enforced (assuming your auth is in the htaccess files). Instead of using `require`, you can route the request using mod_rewrite. So in the htaccess of your root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{QUERY_STRING}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%{QUERY_STRING}/index.php [L]
```